# while Sarah running her own business

Tags: subordinate-clauses, participle-clauses

In the following sentence, can the second "dreams of" be omitted?

> Laura dreams of becoming a chef, while Sarah **dreams of** running her own business.

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb - That doesn't work, because _dreams_ is a verb and your second clause implies _dream_ as a noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Laura dreams of becoming a chef, while Sarah running her own business.

sounds **very wrong**.

On the other hand, this sounds **acceptable**:

> 2. Laura dreams of becoming a chef, Sarah of running her own business.

To my ear, the elision of the verb *dreams* is acceptable in the adjunct in sentence 2, but the elision of *dreams of* is not acceptable in the subordinate clause of sentence 1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Did you notice what is intended to be omitted in the OP sentence is not merely "dreams" but "dreams of"?  If so, you might want to revise your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Apollyon Corrected. My judgment about sentence 1 stands, though.